# Completely centering a form in bootstrap

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using twitter bootstrap to create a website for desktops and mobile phones. I want the login form to be centered both in the x direction and in the y direction.

So if the grid was 100 x 100, then the form would be at 50,50.

I'm able to get the form somewhat to the center of the screen in firefox using `text-align: center;` but firefox puts it a bit off to the right.

What can I do to get to the center?

[Here is my HTML](http://pastebin.com/KTT5T0KM)

[Here is my bootstrap.css](http://pastebin.com/uuwzxAnD)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `margin:auto;` on the `<div>` that contains the form.

Answer (score 0):

That's an awful lot of nested div tags in there, though I know it's partly Bootstrap's fault! One thing I would stress is to make use of the ones that you already have to use with Bootstrap rather than adding new ones to change positioning, because that will create lots of headaches.

After playing with this, I didn't come up with a definite solution, but here's what I think:

- Read up on CSS media queries... this will make the solution to your
  desktop > mobile problem much easier!
- Don't use CSS for a vertical    alignment. Divs aren't table cells
  and can't really act like them. A    small JavaScript that sniffs out
  the width of the screen and does the    positioning math is better. A
  quick Google search will bring up    plenty.